# Selenium cannot write on the 'make a post' window on my Facebook page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im making a python script to make an autopost on my facebook seeling page. but i cant get to write on the little window 'make a post'.
[make a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6grTB.png)

I' ve already tried on change the xpath but i cant get it to work. i' ve seen another codes and xhpx_message_text/xhpc_message doesn' t work. My actual code is...

```
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/This-frutas-107314187288001/")
sleep(5)
post_box=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div')

post_box.click()

sleep(2)
post_box=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div')

post_box.send_keys("This is an automated post.")
```

my actual output is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oyane\Downloads\facecook-selenium-master\login-facebook.py", line 30, in <module>
    post_box.send_keys("This is an automated post.")
  File "C:\Users\oyane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\oyane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\oyane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\oyane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="_3nd0"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think your approach will work as Selenium runs a [clean browser session](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) each time so most probably you will have to log in to your Facebook account first prior to opening any pages
2. Using hard-coded `sleeps` is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, you should be using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead
3. Using absolute XPath locators is not the best option as the locator will be very fragile hence sensitive to markup changes. So I would recommend using relative XPath locators, for example relevant [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for a "What's on your mind" input field would be something like:

   ```
   //textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'on your mind')]
   ```
4. Assuming all above I think you should end up with something like:

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys(
       "your@email.here")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pass"))).send_keys("your_password_here")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Log In']"))).click()

   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
       (By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@aria-label, 'on your mind')]"))).send_keys("your post text")
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i' ve tried the changes that you suggest me (point 2, not yet) but i'm getting the following error.....selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div id="js_16" class="_1mwp navigationFocus _395 _1mwq _4c_p _5bu_ _3t-3 _34nd _21mu _5yk1"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: I know that my xpath is not the correct, but any suggestion on how to get it right ?(i' ve already tried some addons but still not getting it). Thank, you for your help